# How to get an actor within another actor non-blockingly?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Currently in an existging scala akka-http project, we have a bunch of actors that need to tell other actors messages.

In an actor, we would get the reference of the actor via:

```
class OurActor extends Actor {
     private implicit val timeout: Timeout = 15.seconds
     private val otherActor: ActorRef = Await.result[ActorRef](context.system.actorSelection("path/to/other/actor").resolveOne()(timeout), 15.seconds)

       override def receive: Receive = {
    case SomeMessage => {
      ...
      dataSets.foreach(_.foreach(otherActor ! _))
    }
  }
}
```

I am a bit confused by the usage of `Await.result` as this is blocking in the current thread. What alternative can I use?

Comment: When you instantiate all your actors, you can pass/inject the ActorRef of the other actor to `OurActor` - `class OurActor(aRef: ActorRef) extends Actor`

Comment: @ccheneson that's a valid alternative. Can you provide it as an answer please?

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the other actor as a constructor parameter of `OurActor`

```
object OurActor {
  def props(otherActorRef: ActorRef) = Props(classOf[OurActor],otherActorRef)
}


class OurActor(otherActor: ActorRef) extends Actor {
     private implicit val timeout: Timeout = 15.seconds

       override def receive: Receive = {
    case SomeMessage => {
      ...
      otherActor ! _
    }
  }
}
```

When you instantiate your actor:

```
val otherActor = actorSystem.actorOf(OtherActor.props, "otherActor")
val ourActor   = actorSystem.actorOf(OurActor.props(otherActor) "ourActor")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need an actorRef, yet you can also send messages to an actor (or multiple actors even) using the selector directly:

```
class MetronomeJobAlertActor extends Actor {
  private implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))
  private implicit val ec = context.dispatcher
  private implicit val sys = context.system
  private val otherActorSelection: ActorSelection = context.system.actorSelection("path/to/other/actor")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case SomeMessage => {
      ...
      dataSets.foreach(otherActorSelection ! _))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that it is resolvable, maybe you can do the `dataSets.foreach` directly inside the `Future`. Something like this:

```
class OurActor extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
        case SomeMessage => {
            ...
            context.system.actorSelection("path/to/other/actor").resolveOne().map { actorRef => 
                dataSets.foreach(_.foreach(actorRef ! _))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This means that the `dataSets.foreach` statement will happen asynchronously. You will need to be careful if `dataSets` is mutable since things will run in different threads. Also, the `Future` might fail, so you might want to account for that scenario as well.